# A good way to loop and sort on several criteria

Tags: vb.net, loops, conditional-statements

I am working on a project where I have a medium sized list (with anywhere between 10 and 30 items) which I am iterating through.  There is a large list of criteria that is used to sort this list.  In simple terms, I have 5 categories, each of which two counters that tick based off the status of the item.  This is simple for me to do, with either `Switch`/`Case` or just a more basic `If`/`ElseIf`.  What makes this problem more difficult, and in my opinion worthy of outside input, is that each item has a date attached to it, and only 3 items per month should be counted.

My approach to this would be to set up a counter for each month, and then start to ignore items that fall within that month, but I am sure there is a smarter and fancier way to do this and some additional experience would be wonderful insight.

Here is some code to show what I am doing now:

```
For Each item In List
    If item.Category = category1 Then
        If item.status = status1 Then
            category1Status1 = +1
        Else
            category1Status2 = +1
        End If
     ElseIf item.Category = category2 Then
        If item.status = status1 Then
            category2Status1 = +1
        Else
            category2Status2 = +1
        End If
     ElseIf item.Category = category3 Then
        If item.status = status1 Then
            category3Status1 = +1
        Else
            category3Status2 = +1
        End If
     ''More of this looping
     End If
Next
```

EDIT : Perhaps that it would be helpful to note that i can access the date of the item via `item.Date`

Comment: since you are incrementingm it looks like you are counting so, if `List` is a `List(Of T)` (what these things are matters): `status1Count = myList.Where(Function(c) c.Status = category1).Count`

Comment: I would say, a long `LINQ` with `group by` should do it. Clarify a bit more. Show, how you want data to look and list conditions to sort/group. Thanks

Comment: As suggested above, you could probably do something like `List.Group(function(i) i.Category).Where(function(c) c.Count(function(i) i.status = status1) >= 3))` or maybe to a `.Take(3)` to only get the top 3. Sorry if the syntax is off, I haven't done VB in a while...